# JMeter saving test results into file. CLI

Tags: windows, jmeter, command-line-interface

I added 'Simple Data Writer' to my test plan with the next filename path:

```
${__time(Y-MM-dd)}/${__time(HH-mm)}.jtl
```

It works perfectly when I run script from UI but not from command line (script doesn't create folder and saves results into incorrectly named file).

Any ideas how to create folder with date in the name and time in name of .jtl file using Simple Data Writer ?

I'm using windows 10.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

1. Define results file location using __P() function like:

   ```
   ${__P(date,)}/${__P(time,)}.jtl
   ```

   [image: JMeter Property in listener names]
2. Create a batch file to run your JMeter script which will define these `date` and `time` properties using current system date and time via [`-J` command line argument](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options). Example code (you might need to amend it to correspond your operating system regional settings like short date format)

   ```
   @echo off
   For /f "tokens=1-4 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /t') do (set testdate=%%c-%%b-%%a)
   For /f "tokens=1-2 delims=/:/ " %%a in ('time /t') do (set testtime=%%a-%%b)
   jmeter.bat -Jdate=%testdate% -Jtime=%testtime% -n -t test.jmx
   ```
3. Run JMeter test using above batch file - the listener should create the relevant folder and .jtl results file.

See [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) to learn more about JMeter properties and ways of setting, reading and overriding them.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason when running from cli on windows, jmeter doesn't adapt file separators for current os. This solution works for me:

```
${__time(Y-MM-dd)}\\${__time(HH-mm)}.jtl
```